Is there a way of running an AR2 test on a pvargmm output in the panelvar package?
I am using the panelvar package in R to estimate a system GMM model. The result does not report AR2 test results. There is also no in-built function to run the test in the package. Does anyone have any advice on how this test can be run?
  dependent_vars = c("I_K"),
  lags = 1,
  predet_vars=c("employment","employment.L","employment.L2"
  ), 
  exog_vars=c("yr2002","yr2003","yr2004","yr2005","yr2006"
              ,"yr2007", "yr2008", "yr2009","yr2010", "yr2011", "yr2012",
              "yr2013", "yr2014", "yr2015","yr2016", "yr2017", "yr2018", "yr2019"),
  system_constant = FALSE,
  transformation = "fd",
  data = df,
  panel_identifier = c("country", "year"),
  steps = c("twostep"),
  system_instruments = TRUE,
  collapse = TRUE
)```

